# Accessing a Device in the Local Network, but on a Different Subnet Mask

Tags: networking, ip, lan, subnet

I have a device on my local network that has a static IP address of 10.0.0.100 (apparently, this setting is set internally and I cannot change it without accessing the device itself). I have no idea what the subnet mask is, and I wish to gain access to the device so I can change some of its settings, including its IP address and subnet mask.

The problem is, my network is set to 192.168.1.1/24, which I believe currently prevents me from accessing the device, as it's of a different subnet mask.

Is there any way that I can access that device?

Thanks!

Comment: Add a second interface in the appropriate network, and hope that there are only switches and hubs between you and the device.

Comment: The real question is about devices on a _different subnet_. Don't mix up "subnet" and "subnet mask". (The former defines the network's identity, the latter only the size.)

Answer (score 3):

Just change your address temporarily, fix the device, then change back.

Many operating systems even support *multiple* IP addresses (possibly in different subnets) on the same interface. (Windows only supports this with static (i.e. non-DHCP) configurations.)

Be sure to pick an address that's as close as possible – e.g. **`10.0.0.101`** – and minor differences in subnet masks won't be a problem. (Realistically, the other device will be using something from `/8` to `/29`.) You can configure, let's say, `10.0.0.101/24` and it will work, because the other device will be *within* your subnet, and you will be within the device's, and that's the only thing that matters.

(In other words: The subnet mask answers "Is this host local, or do I need to go through my gateway?", so as long as both devices agree on the other being local, it will work.)

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help. What device whose address should I change? Is it the laptop I use to access that device or the gateway (router) of both my laptop and that problematic device? Thanks again!